# Run puppeteer on Chrome No chromium

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, telegram, chromium

I want to open Telegram site with puppeteer

But there is a problem
**Telegram session only opens on Chrome**

You must login with puppeteer each time

There is a way for the puppeteer to run only on the running chrome to detect the session

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
 headless : false,
 executablePath: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
 args: ["--lang=en-US,en", '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-extensions']
```

})

This code works properly
But on chromium

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to run a puppeteer instance on top of an pre-existing Chrome process.

In order to achieve this, first, you need to start the Chrome process with the `remote-debugging-port` option, usually defined as: `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

This [Medium articule](https://medium.com/@jaredpotter1/connecting-puppeteer-to-existing-chrome-window-8a10828149e0) is well detailed on how to achieve so, but to summarize:

- **MAC OS:**

Run:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')
```

- **Windows**:

1. Right click on your Google Chrome shortcut icon => Properties
2. In Target field, add to the very end --remote-debugging-port=9222
   Should look something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Then, you'll be able to navigate to http://localhost:9222/json/version (the port is the same you've defined above), and see an output like this:

```
{
   "Browser": "HeadlessChrome/87.0.4280.66",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "8.7.220.25",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@fd98a29dd59b36f71e4741332c9ad5bda42094bf)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/000aaaa-bb08-55af-a8e3-760dd9998fc7"
}
```

Then, you can use the puppeteer connect() method (instead of the *launch()* method) like this:

```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/000aaaa-bb08-55af-a8e3-760dd9998fc7",
  });
  // now, 'browser' is connected to your chrome window.
  
  // get the opened pages
  const openedPages = await browser.pages();

  // filter out the one you want (telegram). not sure the best way to do it, please test it yourself
  const telegramPage = openedPages.filter(page => page.url().includes("telegram"));
```

Comment: Just adding a note here that "ws://localhost:9222" should be changed with "ws://127.0.0.1:9222" for Puppeteer on NodeJS 17 and 18 if it fails with an ECONNREFUSED error for anyone trying this. Thank you @tmilar for the concise instructions.